# What are a some of the best crosslinkers for uv curing of benzyl methacrylate?

Tags: reaction-mechanism

I'm hoping someone can suggest some crosslinkers for uv curing benzyl methacrylate that are low in viscosity, relatively high in refractive index and most importantly that will impart hardness and rigidity to the produced homopolymer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm hoping someone can suggest crosslinkers for uv curing benzyl methacrylate that are low in viscosity, relatively high in refractive index and that will impart hardness and rigidity to the produced homopolymer.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include this description? This is lot clearer than the actual text of the question.

Comment: Just looking for some free consulting work. For requests such as this a chemist, consultant should be hired given the details and PAID for their work.